# Dirac matrices for generalized metric tensors

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

The Dirac matrices are defined by the relations
$$\left [\gamma^{i},\gamma^{j}\right]_{+}=2\eta^{i,j}\mathbb{1}$$
where $[\cdot,\cdot]_{+}$ is the anti-commutator.

What happens if I replace $\eta^{i,j}$ by a generalized metric tensor $g^{i,j}$ that arises, for instance, from a gravitational field in general relativity?

In particular, if I consider matrices $\gamma^{i}$ that satisfy

$$\left [\gamma^{i},\gamma^{j}\right]_{+}=2g^{i,j}\mathbb{1}$$

and plug these into Dirac's equation (with the derivative replaced by the contravariant derivative), what do the solutions to that "generalized" Dirac equation look like?

Comment: See Michael Brown's answer to [Dirac equation in curved space-time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57568/206691) and the references it cites. The question is different, but the answer includes relevant material.

Comment: By the way, this only works if the manifold admits a **spin structure**. This is mentioned in the answer to [Does Clifford algebra depend on the topology of manifold?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77711/206691). More references about formulating the Dirac equation in curved spacetime are given in [Dirac equation in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/485701/206691) -- same title as the question I cited in the previous comment, but the content is different. The keywords "spin geometry" will also lead you to more information.

Comment: This is a very broad subject. Can you please check the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection#Applications) and try and narrow down your question a bit?

Comment: Another reference that might be of interest is Penrose and Rindler, *Spinors and Space-time*, 2 vols.